# TypeError: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaHighLevelConsumer': in docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, kafkajs

I am starting Zookeeper, kafka and kafdrop with docker-compose in local, everything is works.
when I want to do the same thing inside EC2 instance I get this error.
the EC2 type that I'm using is t2.micro with an OBS in the default VPC and Subnet.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "2"

services:
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafka-web
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:9092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
    networks:
        - nesjs-network

  zookeeper:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3-debian-10'
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - nesjs-network

  kafka:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/kafka:2-debian-10'
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - nesjs-network
```

`

this docker-compos.yaml is working in may local without any issue but she doesn't in my EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in EC2 configuration level.
kafka and kafdrop needs some specific resources such as RAM and vCpu.
instead t2.micro use t2.medium with a volume OBS 30Mo and other resources(vpc subnet sg) by default.
this config work for me.